# FloatingActionButton doesn't show in the design view after setting up the design in the code view

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

Happy nu year all. I set up a floatingActionButton in my Code view but it doesn't show the button in the design view. What seems to be the problem here and how can I fix this?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewOne"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:rippleColor="#FFFFff" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is no problem and you may try to fix it by removing  `app:layout_anchor="@id/viewOne"`

Comment: And if you say there is a problem with your code you need to add that code !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

just write this code ..this will working like a charm

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fabCreateGroup"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/youricon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: It showed in the design view when I replaced the cordinatorLayout with the linear layout but could run the app. Seems this code would only work when its under the coordinator layout. Is there any more answers?

Answer (score 0):

It showed in the design view when I replaced the cordinatorLayout with the linear layout but could run the app. Seems this code would only work when its under the coordinator layout. Is there any more answers?